# Is it possible to add a custom toolbox to your Matlab Compiler Runtime instalation?

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I tried to paste my custom toolbox in default toolbox location.

> /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v85/mcr/toolbox/

It doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the MCR can only execute compiled code.

You would need to include your custom toolbox into a compiled application.